# global宣言は一度だけすればいいというものではないのか

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

初歩的なことなのですが、`global`変数に関する問題です。

```
from PySide import QtGui
import sys

class GlobalTest(QtGui.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(GlobalTest,self).__init__(parent=None)

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        if g_is_modified == True:
            message = QtGui.QMessageBox().warning(None,"Warning-警告","書き換えられた内容があります。このまま閉じてもよろしいですか？\n",QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok,QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel)
            if message == QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok:
                pass
            else:
                return
        print(15,global_widget.parent() == self)
        return QtGui.QTextEdit.closeEvent(self,event)
    def focusInEvent(self,event):
        print("focus ｷﾀ")
        global g_is_modified
        g_is_modified = True
        global_widget.setParent(self)
        return QtGui.QTextEdit.focusInEvent(self,event)
def main():

    try:
        QtGui.QApplication([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(19,e)
    global g_is_modified
    g_is_modified = False
    global global_widget
    global_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    glob = GlobalTest()
    glob.show()

    sys.exit(QtGui.QApplication.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`main()`関数内で、一度、`global`宣言をし、`g_is_modified = False`を入れ込んでいます。
 この変数の値は、`focusInEvent`に入った時に、上書きされるようにしています。
一方で、もう一つ、`global`宣言をし、次は、`global`ウィジェットをグローバル化しています。同様に、このウィジェットの親を、`focusInEvent`に入った時に`GlobalTest`に設定しています。
　結果は、

```
15 True
16 True
```

で問題ありません。これは、解決後の問題です。(最初はなぜ上書きできないのだろうということが疑問でしたが、どちらでもglobal宣言をしたらOKでした。)
解決前は、`focusInEvent`内では、`global`宣言をしておりませんでした。

```
def focusInEvent(self,event):
    print("focus ｷﾀ")

    g_is_modified = True
    global_widget.setParent(self)
    return QtGui.QTextEdit.focusInEvent(self,event)
```

結果

```
15 False
16 True
```

`g_is_modified`の値は上書きされませんでした。

`g_is_modified`は、再度`global`宣言をしなければ値が上書きされることはありませんが、`widget`は、一度`global`宣言をすれば、値が更新されました。この違いはなんでしょうか？単なる変数と、クラスの一メソッドなので、全くの別物のため、なんとなく理由はわかりますが、わかりやすく説明していただくことは出来ますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pythonでは、代入をおこなうとローカルスコープになります。

g_is_modified は、代入がされているのでglobal文がなければlocal変数になり、global_widget の方は代入されていないのでglobal変数が使われます。

公式のチュートリアルだと以下のように説明されています。

https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97

> Python 特有の癖として、代入を行うと – どの global 文も有効でない場合は – 名前がいつも最も内側のスコープに入るというものがあります。代入はデータのコピーを行いません — 単に名前をオブジェクトに結びつける (bind) だけです。オブジェクトの削除でも同じです: del x は、 x をローカルスコープが参照している名前空間から削除します。実際、新たな名前を導入する操作は全てローカルスコープを用います。とりわけ、 import 文や関数定義は、モジュールや関数の名前をローカルスコープに結び付けます。

Comment: よくわかりました！PySideやPyQtは関係ないということ。その場で代入するとローカルスコープ化するのですね！

Comment: Pythonでクラスを使う場合は、global変数ではなくて、クラスの方でクラス変数、インスタンス変数を定義して使った方がミスが少なくなると思います。

Comment: クラス変数＝インスタンス化無しでも使える固定変数ですね？了解です。